# Can memories intentionally be overwritten, or forgotten?

Tags: brain, memory

Over the years, I've come across studies (e.g., [here](http://www.donnajobridge.com/pdf/bridge12.pdf), [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/182f/c325ed71ab84bbb806cd29ef1f9fa15fa134.pdf), and [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3183109/)), and have watched documentaries (similar to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_QbTX2qS10)), that speak about memory retrieval, and how that, every time you recall a memory, that memory is subject to being distorted (less accurate). Of the different types of memory, it seems that this is most often spoken about when [episodic memory](http://memory.ucsf.edu/brain/memory/episodic) is involved.

In pretty much every situation I've seen, the person with the memory is trying their best to *most accurately* recall that memory, with respect to the true event(s) that was originally experienced. However, would it be possible to *intentionally* cause memory distortion, perhaps by continuously recalling a memory and then deliberately thinking of false information? Or, can this process only happen subconsciously?

There is a movie that somewhat plays on this idea, [Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0338013/). In this movie, a participant is alseep while wearing a kind of [helmet](https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/_YKGggSbNTlSL2xfLf7b8r2_vas=/800x0/filters:no_upscale()/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/5897657/800px-EEG_Recording_Cap.0.jpg) that selectively targets and erases desired-to-be-forgotten memories. And though my initial curiosity did not arise from seeing this movie, and yes, I am aware that this movie is sci-fi, I do still wonder if this kind of overall effect could be achieved without technological/medical intervention. If not, why?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63756/discussion-on-question-by-charles-can-memories-intentionally-be-overwritten-or).